# Sql query taking too much time

Tags: mysql, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have two tables in the database wp_rg_lead_details and wp_service_request.
My query is:

```
$results1=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE lead_id in ( SELECT entry_id FROM wp_service_request)  and  form_id =1 AND field_number  in (1,39,2)");
```

When I run this query it is taking too much time causing the page to time out.
The inner query is running successfully when executed separately.

There are about 12000 records in both the tables. How should I optimize it so that my page loads faster?

Comment: try this: SELECT * FROM wp_rg_lead_detail as a WHERE lead_id in (SELECT entry_id FROM wp_service_request WHERE entry_id = a.lead_id)  and  form_id =1 AND field_number  in (1,39,2)

Comment: notice that your subquery is always loading the full table of wp_service_request for each row in wp_rg_lead_detail. that's probably your main issue and that's what i tried to solve by adding a where clause to the sub query. the same can be achieved using a join query

Comment: I think you need to take care of the IN clause because it will look at the whole table and scan the matching lead_id . It also depends on the records it needs to match . For eg if the table wp_service_request has 1000 rows it needs to look at all the 1000 rows meaning it  takes time. Avoid using IN Clause . Rather join like this,    SELECT rg_lead.* 
FROM wp_rg_lead_detail AS rg_lead
INNER JOIN wp_service_request as servreq ON servreq.PK_Key = rg_lead.FK_MatchingFK_Key
WHERE rg_lead.lead_id = servreq.entry_id 
AND rg_lead.form_id =1 AND rg_lead.field_number  in (1,39,2) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the inner query seperately and then use its result to fetch 
data in main query.
Try this

```
$results=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT entry_id FROM wp_service_requests");

$flag = 1;
$str = "(";
foreach ($results as $result) {
  if($flag ==1)
  {
    $str  = $str . "'" . $result->entry_id . "'" ;
    $flag=2;
  }
  else 
  {
    $str = $str . ",'" . $result->entry_id . "'" ;
  }
}

$str .=  ")";


$results1=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE lead_id in " . $str ."  and  form_id =1 AND field_number  in (1,39,2)");
```

I recommend if you do not need the full data from the "wp_service_requests" try using filters to minimize the data.

Comment: I need all the entries from the second table.
But Thanks! it worked for me.